# Test Class for trigger with external id

Tags: apex

I am trying to come up with a test class for the trigger below.
The process is that the JDE_Number__c value is passed into the Sales_Program__c object.  Each account has a JDE number so I need to get the Account ID for the Account based on the JDE number.  The trigger works fine but I am a bit confused on the test class.  Do I need to create a test Account along with the Sales_Program__c record? Can I supply a account id in the Test Class?
Thank you for your help.
M

```
trigger GetAccountIdFromJDENum on Sales_Program__c (before insert) 
{
    Map<String, Id> accountMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    Set<String> JDENUMs = new Set<String>();
        for(Sales_Program__c JDENUM : Trigger.new)

            {
                JDENUMs.add( JDENUM.JDE_Number__c );
            }


        for( Account acc : [ SELECT Id, JDE__c  FROM Account where JDE__c IN: JDENUMs ])
        {
            accountMap.put( acc.JDE__c, acc.Id );
        }

                for (Sales_Program__c JDENUM : Trigger.new)
                {
                    JDENUM.Account__c = accountMap.get(JDENUM.JDE_Number__c); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers are tested fairly easy, yes, all you need is create appropriate data set and insert/update it. In your case it is Account and Sales_Program__c.

Yes Account will have ID after insertion in test (no, you can not specify ID, but you can specify your external ID).

```
@isTest (SeeAllData = false)
public class myTestClass {

@isTest
public static void MyTestExample () {
    Account accRecord = new Account();
    accRecord.JDE__c = "VALUE";
    // add all other required fields / dependencies
    insert accRecord;

    test.startTest();
    Sales_Program__c spRecord = new spRecord();
    spRecord.JDE_Number__c = "VALUE";
    insert spRecord;
    test.stopTest();

    spRecordResult = [select id,Account__c from Sales_Program__c where id=:spRecord.id];

    system.assertEquals(accRecord.ID,spRecordResult.Account__c);
} 
}
```

VALUE should be same.

Comment: always good to show new community members the use of `system.assert`

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback.  I am receiving an error regarding the spRecordResult variable.  Its stating the variable does not exist.  I tried to assign it as a string but it gave me an error for an illegal assignment from List to String.  Also I changed part of the test code from  Sales_Program__c spRecord = new spRecord();   to  Sales_Program__c spRecord = new Sales_Program__c(); since I was getting an error.  Is this correct? Thanks agian to you both. M